# WPF Marquee Text Animation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, marquee

I can scroll text with `TranslateTransform` but when the animation is close to finishing I'd like it to begin again. Like a snake :)

This is what I've got:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="-40"/>
    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    <StackPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="-900" Duration="00:00:10"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </StackPanel.Triggers>
    <TextBlock FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Margin="10,0,7,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This is what I'd like:

[image]

Comment: What's the question? What's the desired behavior, what's the behavior you get?

Comment: Question is; i want to marquee text but like as snake

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you paint a picture? Or point us to a place where you've seen this effect before?

Comment: Picture; http://postimage.org/image/k0x636tgx/

Comment: +1 and edited for clarity. I don't think you can do it with one `<TextBlock>`, you probably need two or more. I tried putting something together but for me the translate animation would only show stuff that was visible on screen when the animation started. Kind of useless this using two TextBlock's requires one to be offscreen when the animation starts.

Comment: can anyone please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933660/wpf-text-marquee-animation/21934028

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

You can add a `Canvas` to the `StackPanel` with 2 `TextBlocks` one set to position 0 and one set to the `ActualWidth` of the `StackPanel`, then when the first block of text goes offscreen the other block will come into view.

The reason I used `Canvas` is because `Canvas` is the only element that actually supports `ClipToBounds="false"` this allows the 2nd `TextBlock` to be visible even if its placed outside the bounds of the `Canvas` itself

We also need a `IValueConverter` to get the correct negative value if you want to scroll from right to left.

I also added event trigger on `SizeChanged` so if the window is resized the animation values will update correctly.

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication9
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class NegatingConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                return -((double)value);
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                return +(double)value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="83" Width="222" Name="UI" Tag="Tol Level">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
            <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}" Duration="00:00:10"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.SizeChanged">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
            <TextBlock Text="StackOverflow" FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Canvas.Left="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtKron}" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

**Edit:** Left to Right

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
            <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas}" Duration="00:00:10"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.SizeChanged">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
            <TextBlock Text="StackOverflow" FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Canvas.Left="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtKron}" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi
It's really great. 

I'm working on it buttom to top :) but i have one problem about this; 
when first block to top (actually one image) it's going to top=0 but image is almost top=50, i didn't fix this. Thank you!

Comment: There is a problem here - The animation does not start. I fixed it in the code behind by adding a Loaded event and in it: Storyboard sb = (Storyboard) this.stack.FindResource("slide");

            stack.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() =>
            {
                sb.Begin();
            }));

Comment: Remove the converter from the animations `To` property and add it to the `Canvas.Left` property of the last `TextBlock`, added example above

Comment: A quick heads-up : in the ConvertBack method of the converter in your solution the + (unary) operator does nothing. You should use the same code as in Convert to ConvertBack.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I try with your code . but i got error in local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" ----The name "NegatingConverter" does not exist in the namespace. how to solve it?

Comment: What about when the text is long and cannot fit in the TextBlock? Then the two TextBlock overlap and things get ugly.

Comment: Shouldn't the `ConvertBack` method be the same as `Convert` in the NegatingConverter?

Comment: Hi this works well but there is an overlap when the text is quite long. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @SepehrM could you fix the overlap?

Comment: @mrid Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

The code in above answer does not produce continuous scroll. Here is the code for continuous smooth scroll.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Margin="6,83,9,0" Name="ViewingBox" Background="YellowGreen" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="-2" Height="49" Name="BoxOne" FontSize="20">I need breakfast.</Label>
            <Label Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="-2" Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="BoxTwo" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20">You can have oranges and egg.</Label>
        </Canvas>   
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VB Code Behind:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Public Enum Texts
    BoxOne
    BoxTwo
End Enum

Class Window1
    Private dubAnim As New DoubleAnimation()
    Private dubAnim2 As New DoubleAnimation()
    Private NewsTimer As New Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
    Dim leadText As Texts = Texts.BoxOne

    Private Sub Window1_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        dubAnim.From = ViewingBox.ActualWidth
        dubAnim.To = -BoxOne.ActualWidth
        dubAnim.SpeedRatio = 0.05
        AddHandler dubAnim.Completed, AddressOf dubAnim_Completed
        Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(dubAnim, 320)
        BoxOne.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, dubAnim)

        dubAnim2.From = ViewingBox.ActualWidth
        dubAnim2.To = -BoxTwo.ActualWidth
        dubAnim2.SpeedRatio = 0.05
        Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(dubAnim2, 320)
        AddHandler dubAnim2.Completed, AddressOf dubAnim2_Completed

        AddHandler NewsTimer.Tick, AddressOf NewsTimer_Tick
        NewsTimer.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0.9)
        NewsTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewsTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim BoxOneLocation As Point = BoxOne.TranslatePoint(New Point(0, 0), ViewingBox)
        Dim BoxTwoLocation As Point = BoxTwo.TranslatePoint(New Point(0, 0), ViewingBox)

        If leadText = Texts.BoxOne Then
            Dim loc As Double = BoxOneLocation.X + BoxOne.ActualWidth
            If loc < ViewingBox.ActualWidth / 1.5 Then
                BoxTwo.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, dubAnim2)
                NewsTimer.Stop()
            End If
        Else
            Dim loc As Double = BoxTwoLocation.X + BoxTwo.ActualWidth
            If loc < ViewingBox.ActualWidth / 1.5 Then
                BoxOne.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, dubAnim)
                NewsTimer.Stop()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub dubAnim_Completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        leadText = Texts.BoxTwo
        NewsTimer.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub dubAnim2_Completed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        leadText = Texts.BoxOne
        NewsTimer.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Exteding the [answer of sa_ddam213](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328839/7311767),  this is a revise of the first animation(Right to Left). This will work for long strings. :)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    x:Name="stack" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="0"                        >

            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <local1:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
                <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}" 
                                     To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=txtKron, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}" 
                                     Duration="00:00:30"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny2"
                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <Label Content="{Binding Path=RSSFeed}" 
                       x:Name="txtKron" 
                       Canvas.Left="0"
                       Foreground="#E9D460"
                       Padding="0"
                       Margin="0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <Label.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.SizeChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>

                <Label.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny2" X="0"/>
                </Label.RenderTransform>
            </Label>

        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# version of [Leon Munir's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17087117/5740382)

[image: Animation preview]

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="TextAnimation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextAnimation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Margin="6,83,9,0" Name="ViewingBox" Background="YellowGreen" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Label Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="-2" Height="49" Name="BoxOne" FontSize="20">I need breakfast.</Label>
            <Label Canvas.Left="263" Canvas.Top="-2" Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="BoxTwo" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20">You can have oranges and egg.</Label>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace TextAnimation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DoubleAnimation dubAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
        private DoubleAnimation dubAnim2 = new DoubleAnimation();
        private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer NewsTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        private Texts leadText = Texts.BoxOne;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += Window1_Loaded;
        }



        private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dubAnim.From = ViewingBox.ActualWidth;
            dubAnim.To = -BoxOne.ActualWidth;
            dubAnim.SpeedRatio = 0.05d;
            dubAnim.Completed += DubAnim_Completed;
            Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(dubAnim, 320);
            BoxOne.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, dubAnim);

            dubAnim2.From = ViewingBox.ActualWidth;
            dubAnim2.To = -BoxTwo.ActualWidth;
            dubAnim2.SpeedRatio = 0.05d;
            Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(dubAnim2, 320);
            dubAnim2.Completed += DubAnim2_Completed;

            NewsTimer.Tick += NewsTimer_Tick;
            NewsTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)Math.Round(0.9));
            NewsTimer.Start();
        }

        private void NewsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Point BoxOneLocation = BoxOne.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), ViewingBox);
            Point BoxTwoLocation = BoxTwo.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), ViewingBox);

            if (leadText == Texts.BoxOne)
            {
                double loc = BoxOneLocation.X + BoxOne.ActualWidth;
                if (loc < ViewingBox.ActualWidth / 1.5d)
                {
                    BoxTwo.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, dubAnim2);
                    NewsTimer.Stop();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                double loc = BoxTwoLocation.X + BoxTwo.ActualWidth;
                if (loc < ViewingBox.ActualWidth / 1.5d)
                {
                    BoxOne.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, dubAnim);
                    NewsTimer.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        private void DubAnim_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            leadText = Texts.BoxTwo;
            NewsTimer.Start();
        }

        private void DubAnim2_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            leadText = Texts.BoxOne;
            NewsTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

*Texts.cs*

```
namespace TextAnimation
{
    public enum Texts
    {
        BoxOne,
        BoxTwo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a more simple Marquee Text from the links below (For my case only, so pleasetry it first), for more like upwards and downwards you can check with the links

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48267/Making-a-Simple-Marquee-Text-Control-Drip-Animatio

For Details can check the following pictures:

[The picture of starting from right to left at begining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvBnm.png)

[Ending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gZSL.png)

xaml:

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True"
                 Name="canMain"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Background="YellowGreen"
                 Height="35">
            <TextBlock  Name="tbmarquee"
                        Text="Testing 123~ Testing 123~ Testing 123~"
                            FontSize="24"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
        </Canvas>
```

C# code
For Left to right

```
private void LeftToRightMarquee()
{
    double height = canMain.ActualHeight - tbmarquee.ActualHeight;
    tbmarquee.Margin = new Thickness(0, height / 2, 0, 0);
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new 
    Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_marqueeTimeInSeconds));
    tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```

Right To Left

```
private void RightToLeftMarquee()
{
    double height = canMain.ActualHeight - tbmarquee.ActualHeight;
    tbmarquee.Margin = new Thickness(0, height / 2, 0, 0);
    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualWidth;
    doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    doubleAnimation.Duration = new 
    Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_marqueeTimeInSeconds));
    tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```