# Xaml Doubleanimation targetproperty crashes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to animate my Label inside of canvas from canvas right to canvas left + size of label, infinitely. Which means my label comes from the right side and goes to the left till the end and then again repeats.

This is my xaml:

```
        <Canvas Margin="0, 0, 0, 20" Name="CanMain2" Height="30" Width="350"  >
        <Label x:Name="LabelNameSong" Content="Hello" >
            <Label.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="Scroll">
                    <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LabelNameSong}" Duration="00:00:10"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Right)"
          Storyboard.TargetName="LabelNameSong"
          RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Label.Resources>

            <Label.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Scroll}" />
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.SizeChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Scroll}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
    </Canvas>
```

As soon as I launch app it crashes, and debugger says:

> Cannot animate the 'Right' property on a
>   'System.Windows.Controls.Label' using a
>   'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the
>   inner exception.

I am new to xaml and can't seem to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Canvas.Right` is an `AttachedProperty` but you have not attached the property to your `Label`

If you add the `AttachedProperty` to your `Label` it will then let you animate the value as the Property will be registered(attached) to the `Label`

Example:

```
  <Canvas Margin="0, 0, 0, 20" Name="CanMain2" Height="30" Width="350"  >
        <Label x:Name="LabelNameSong" Content="Hello" Canvas.Right="0" >
            <Label.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="Scroll">
                    <DoubleAnimation To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LabelNameSong}" Duration="00:00:10"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Right)"
          Storyboard.TargetName="LabelNameSong"
          RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Label.Resources>

            <Label.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Scroll}" />
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.SizeChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Scroll}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Label.Triggers>
        </Label>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for checking into my topic again, I actually took your advice to use xaml for this instead of code-behind (for MVVM approach). After I added `AttachedProperty` to my `Label` I got this error: `Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Canvas.Right'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.` By the way, can you elaborate a little more what is `AttachedProperty`?

Comment: I added the exact Xaml I tested to my answer above, and here is a link explaining AttachedProperties(it will explain it better than me,LOL) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx

Comment: You tested this example above? Wow weird, I changed it before you pasted your code and had the same code, but it crashed and still crashes, will try to make a new project. Thanks for link i will read it.

Comment: Ohh oops sorry, I replicated your crash by removing the `()` from `Canvas.Right`, it should be `(Canvas.Right)`, Try the code above again :) that can be explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451.aspx

Comment: Oh yes, that is very nice from you that you give me links. I will have a nice read tonight! By the way, there is no other way to put "negative from" like From="-{Binding ActualWidth}" or similar to start or to move from visible area in the end, than implementing that NegativeConverter you showed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation ? You know in code behind you can just set `doubleAnimation.From = -nameLabel.ActualWidth;` negative FROM. But you can't do that directly in xaml? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Unfortunatly there is no way to negate a value directly in Xaml, converter is the only nice way

Comment: Thank you sa_ddam213! I appreciate your help.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm facing the same and the code here does not work for me. Actually... the comment talks about AttachedProperty, but it is nowhere in the code example. What am I missing?