# Need help creating a scrolling textblock,

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a scrolling text control.

I have a grid with 2 columns. At the moment the scrolling text goes over the left column, but I don't want that.

[image]

code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="83" Width="350" Name="UI" Tag="Tol Level">


<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <WrapPanel Background="Red" Grid.Column="0" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
            <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}" Duration="00:00:02"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.SizeChanged">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
            <TextBlock Text="StackOverflow" FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Canvas.Left="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtKron}" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code behind :

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class NegatingConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return -((double)value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return +(double)value;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
}
```

I used this answer as inspiration :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328839/1271907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, the order that you declare your XAML elements is reflected by their Z-index value (front to back). Therefore, the simplest fix for your problem is simply to move the `WrapPanel` to the bottom of your code, eg. declare it last, where it will then be on top of the scrolling `TextBlock`:

```
...
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
            <TextBlock Text="StackOverflow" FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Canvas.Left="0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtKron}" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel Background="Red" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>
```