# Creating a marquee lookalike in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, marquee

im trying to create the equivalent of this(html)

```html
<marquee behavior="alternate">Your bouncing text goes here</marquee>
```

in a Windows Store App, with C#
is there any control that can do this or do i have to create a custom one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no Marquee controls in Windows Store Apps.

I have managed to find code doing something similar to what you are trying to do. Go take a look at [WPF Marquee Text Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation). If you play around with that code you should be able to get the wanted result

The main difference with your Marquee is that once you reach the edge of the screen you want to go back the other way. Something as simple as getting the `Width` of your `textblock` and your `grid` and substracting them could give you the wanted result

One way to do it would be something like this :

1. Get the width difference of your controls

   ```
   int TotalMargin = gridTest.Width - textblocktest.Width
   ```
2. You would then need to add continuously a value to your margin

   ```
   if textblocktest.Margin.Left < TotalMargin {
       textBlock.Margin = New Thickness(textblock.Margin.Left + aNumber,0,0,0)
   }
   else{
       //Call a procedure doing the same thing but decrementing the margin until it is at 0 and then going back to adding margin
   }
   ```