# WPF text scroll animation

Tags: wpf, animation

How do you create a control that horizontally scrolls the text to show text that are to long?

So instead of character overflow i would like it to scroll from side to side.

I've seen controls that does a continues scroll but that's not what i look for.

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so we can help you from that please?

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of marquee control? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation

Comment: I have no example as i did not try to code one simply because i don't know how it should be done.. 

Yes it's like the marqeee control, but it should not scroll to either left or right, but if the text is to long to be shown, it should scroll left until reaching the end of the text, wait a few seconds and then scroll the text back to the beginning..

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear wih your Question.  Something like this.

```
 <TextBox Width="500" Height="50" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

Dont know where I have to put animation here :)

Comment: No i need it to automatically scroll/slide the text from side to side to show all text if it overflows. It has nothing to do with scrollbars