# WPF marquee text animation scrolls across other controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I implemented the solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation), in a window with XAML given below. I am trying to make a scrolling marquee text effect for a label:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfMarqueeText.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfMarqueeText="clr-namespace:WpfMarqueeText"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="Aqua">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,3,5,3" Fill="#b933ad"/>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Z" Foreground="White" FontFamily="HelveticaBold" FontSize="150" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3,5,3"/>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Some Info:" FontFamily="HelveticaBold" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,3,5,3"/>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <wpfMarqueeText:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
                            <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}" Duration="00:00:10"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
                        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <StackPanel.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.SizeChanged">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </StackPanel.Triggers>

                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
                            <Label FontFamily="HelveticaBold" FontSize="18" Margin="5,3,5,3"  x:Name="Label1" Content="Blah blah blah" Canvas.Left="0"/>
                            <Label Name="Label2" Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=Label1}" FontFamily="HelveticaBold" FontSize="18" Margin="5,3,5,3" Canvas.Left="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}"/>
                        </Canvas>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You must also define the NegatingConverter class in the code-behind:

```
public class NegatingConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return -((double)value);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            return +(double)value;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

This produces the desired efect, however the text animation scrolls over the other UI elements as seen in the images below (sorry, I don't have enough rep to post images):

http://tinypic.com/r/df8zeu/9
http://tinypic.com/r/2inc3r/9

So, is there any way to fix the animation so that the text only scrolls within the boundary of the grid column it is contained within, or within the boundaries of the label itself? Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48267/Making-a-Simple-Marquee-Text-Control-Drip-Animatio should help u

Comment: Awesome, thank you for posting this. I will try to implement this in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article linked by Akanksha in response to my OP shows how to create a user control that produces a clean, scrolling text effect. You can also specify 4 different scroll directions, left <-> right and up <-> down. I'll give my implementation here for others:

XAML for MarqueeTextUserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AaronLuna.Common.UI.UserControls.MarqueeTextUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <Canvas ClipToBounds="True" Name="CanvasMain">
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockMain"/>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl>
```

Code for MarqueeTextUserControl:

```
namespace AaronLuna.Common.UI.UserControls
{        
    public partial class MarqueeTextUserControl
    {
        public MarqueeTextUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CanvasMain.Height = Height;
            CanvasMain.Width = Width;
        }

        public ScrollDirection ScrollDirection { get; set; }
        public double ScrollDurationInSeconds { get; set; }
        public String Text { set { TextBlockMain.Text = value; }}

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollText(ScrollDirection);
        }

        public void ScrollText(ScrollDirection scrollDirection)
        {
            switch (scrollDirection)
            {
                case ScrollDirection.LeftToRight:
                    LeftToRightMarquee();
                    break;
                case ScrollDirection.RightToLeft:
                    RightToLeftMarquee();
                    break;
                case ScrollDirection.TopToBottom:
                    TopToBottomMarquee();
                    break;
                case ScrollDirection.BottomToTop:
                    BottomToTopMarquee();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void LeftToRightMarquee()
        {
            double height = CanvasMain.ActualHeight - TextBlockMain.ActualHeight;
            TextBlockMain.Margin = new Thickness(0, height/2, 0, 0);

            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = -TextBlockMain.ActualWidth,
                To = CanvasMain.ActualWidth,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ScrollDurationInSeconds))
            };

            TextBlockMain.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, doubleAnimation);
        }

        private void RightToLeftMarquee()
        {
            double height = CanvasMain.ActualHeight - TextBlockMain.ActualHeight;
            TextBlockMain.Margin = new Thickness(0, height/2, 0, 0);

            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = -TextBlockMain.ActualWidth,
                To = CanvasMain.ActualWidth,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ScrollDurationInSeconds))
            };

            TextBlockMain.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
        }

        private void TopToBottomMarquee()
        {
            double width = CanvasMain.ActualWidth - TextBlockMain.ActualWidth;
            TextBlockMain.Margin = new Thickness(width/2, 0, 0, 0);

            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = -TextBlockMain.ActualHeight,
                To = CanvasMain.ActualHeight,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ScrollDurationInSeconds))
            };

            TextBlockMain.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, doubleAnimation);
        }

        private void BottomToTopMarquee()
        {
            double width = CanvasMain.ActualWidth - TextBlockMain.ActualWidth;
            TextBlockMain.Margin = new Thickness(width/2, 0, 0, 0);

            var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = -TextBlockMain.ActualHeight,
                To = CanvasMain.ActualHeight,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ScrollDurationInSeconds))
            };

            TextBlockMain.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, doubleAnimation);
        }
    }

    public enum ScrollDirection
    {
        LeftToRight,
        RightToLeft,
        TopToBottom,
        BottomToTop
    }
}
```

Client XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MarqueeTextExampleUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:AaronLuna.Common.UI.UserControls;assembly=AaronLuna.Common"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="Some Info:"/>
        <userControls:MarqueeTextUserControl x:Name="MarqueeTextBlock"/>
    </DockPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Client Code:

```
MarqueeTextBlock.Text = "Blah blah blah";
MarqueeTextBlock.ScrollDirection = ScrollDirection.RightToLeft;
MarqueeTextBlock.ScrollDurationInSeconds = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty-solution:

Change your `Label` to

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Some Info:" FontFamily="HelveticaBold" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="5,3,5,3" Panel.ZIndex="99" Background="Aqua"/>
```

The `Panel.ZIndex` brings the `Label` to front. And making the `Background` not Transparent gives the desired look. The boundries are still not perfect, but this should give you a clue on how to handle Layers

Comment: Thanks! I was trying something similar but applying the ZIndex to the wrong XAML elements, I guess.