# UWP Marquee Text Animation

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a uwp version of marquee text animation.

And I want the same effect like [WPF Marquee Text Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation).

When the pointer entered the grid item, marquee text start to animate.
When the pointer exited the grid item, marquee text stop to animate.

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking about handle point enter, point leave event and then use two textblock in a canvas to have this animation. It may need some time for me to write the code out. I will post it out later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UWP version which I wrote based on the answer you provided from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation). It's just a demo and you need to customize it yourself to meet your requirement.

Please create a usercontrol first and here is XAML code in the usercontrol:

```html
     <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" Width="265" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited" x:Name="mygrid">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter"/>
            <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                            Duration="0:0:6" From="0"
                            To="{Binding Width,ElementName=canvas,Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel x:Name="mystack" Height="500" Background="AliceBlue">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack" Height="100">
                    <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
                    </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
                    <TextBlock Text="TestTesting" FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Canvas.Left="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtKron}" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

Here is the code behind:

```cs
     private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard1.Begin();
        }

        private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard1.Stop();
        }
```

And the converter:

```
     public class NegatingConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                return -((double)value);
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value is double)
            {
                return +(double)value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

And there is a portential problem. I will meet confict problem when I do not set the background of the above mystack stackpanel.