# How to display a surplus of text on small resolutions

Tags: c#, xaml, text, uwp

I'm creating an app in C# uwp and I'm having a problem with text wrapping. On small resolutions (mobile phones) my text that is placed in a XAML text block isn't displaying the entirety of it, only the part that can fit in the screen, I'd like to be able to implement a scrolling function, but I couldn't find a solution. Should I use a different type of text block or is there an easy way to make a scrolling text?

Comment: For scrolling text see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328839/7565574

Answer (score 0):

Put the TextBlock into a ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Text="Lots of text here..." TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="80"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```