# C# Why don't stop sotryboard in Ticker stackPanel

Tags: wpf

Here TextAnimation.xaml
I want to storyboard TickerStoryBoard pause and start

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <WrapPanel Background="Red" Grid.Column="0" >
        </WrapPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stack">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <local:NegatingConverter x:Key="NegatingConverter" />
                <Storyboard x:Key="slide" x:Name="TickerStoryBoard">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas, Converter={StaticResource NegatingConverter}}" Duration="00:00:01"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                      Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                      RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.SizeChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=stack}">
                <TextBlock Text="StackOverflow" FontSize="25"  x:Name="txtKron" Canvas.Left="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtKron}" FontSize="25" Canvas.Left="{Binding Width, ElementName=canvas}"/>
            </Canvas>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Button x:Name="StopButton" Content="멈춰" PreviewMouseDown="StopButton_PreviewMouseDown" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

from this [WPF Marquee Text Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323163/wpf-marquee-text-animation/15328839#15328839)

I Can't stop

```
private void StopButton_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard= stack.Resources["slide"] as Storyboard;
            storyboard.Stop();
        }
```

Why can i sotryboard stop ?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because of the way your storyboard is started.

Essentially, a storyboard is not controllable unless you use begin(true) to start it.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts#:~:text=To%20make%20a%20storyboard%20controllable,it%20to%20its%20fill%20period](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts#:%7E:text=To%20make%20a%20storyboard%20controllable,it%20to%20its%20fill%20period).

> To make a storyboard controllable, you use the Begin method and specify true as the second parameter. You can then use the storyboard's interactive methods to pause, resume, seek, stop, speed up, or slow down the storyboard, or advance it to its fill period. The following is a list of the storyboard's interactive methods:

> .....

> Stop: Stops the storyboard.

You can only do that if you start the storyboard programmatically.

You could remove the storyboard using xaml or code.

Similarly to <beginstoryboard   there's a <Removestoryboard